# How to use Google translate text to speech API using $http in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, text-to-speech, google-text-to-speech

I'm trying to leverage Google TTS API in association with Angular. However I keep coping 404 error. For example, here's a piece of my code:

```
term.wordVoiceUrl = 'http://www.translate.google.com/translate_tts?tl=fi&q=paiva';
term.wordAudio=new Audio(term.wordVoiceUrl);
term.wordAudio.play();
```

I don't understand why when I enter the link with the browser it works fine but when I request it in my code it returns a 404 error?

Comment: Something is wrong with your URL: 'http://www.translate.google.com/translate_tts?tl=fi&q=paiva'

Comment: Sr, I typed a little bit incorrectly but yeah the problem is still there!